# Nested foreach loop unexpected result

Tags: php

I'm having a big issue with nested foreachs in my project, and I don't know how to properly solve it.

I have the following scenario:

There is a form that the user can add or delete sessions, and other kind of data. I want to check if the user edited the sessions or not, if the user didn't edited any data inside the sessions, then I don't need to check for other stuffs and edit data inside de database.

When I create a new customer, it's created his sessions, like:

```
date= "2018-12-12"
startTime= "13:00"
endTime= "14:00"
```

A customer can have multiple sessions in a week.

Then I have the customer profile, where I can edit some data and also edit his sessions, like the date, startTime and endTime, add more sessions or delete them.
The point is that, when I get into the backend, I get the weekly sessions that I stored when I created him:

```
array:2 [▼
    1 => array:3 [▼
    "weekDay" => "3" //Wednesday
    "startTime" => "14:00:00"
    "endTime" => "15:00:00"
]
0 => array:3 [▼
    "weekDay" => "2" //Tuesday
    "startTime" => "14:00:00"
    "endTime" => "15:00:00"
  ]
]
```

And the sessions that are coming from the form:

```
array:2 [▼
    1 => array:3 [▼
    "weekDay" => "3"
    "startTime" => "14:00:00"
    "endTime" => "15:00:00"
]
0 => array:3 [▼
    "weekDay" => "2"
    "startTime" => "14:00:00"
    "endTime" => "15:00:00"
  ]
]
```

In this situation, I haven't edited the sessions, only other data. When It happen, I have the following foreach checking if the data has changed or not:

```
foreach($periodWeek as $periodDay) {
    foreach($weekDays as $weekDay) {
        if ($weekDay['weekDay'] == $periodDay['weekDay'] &&
            $weekDay['startTime'] == $periodDay['startTime'] &&
            $weekDay['endTime'] == $periodDay['endTime'])
        {
            break;
        }
        } else {
            $sessions[] = $weekDay;
        }
    }
}
```

$periodWeek are the sessions stored In the database and $weekDays are the sessions coming from the form.

I was expecting to get an empty array, because "everything" is equals. I know I did a dumb mistake by doing this, because when the foreach loops through it, it gets the result like that:

[The result of the foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgk6C.png)

1 and 2 are equals, then it breaks from the loop, thats what I wanted so far.
Then it jumps to line 5 in the image. That's where I implode, because I have no idea what to do there, since 5 and 6 are not equals, even though 7 and 8 are. Then i get the following result:

```
array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
    "weekDay" => "2"
    "startTime" => "14:00:00"
    "endTime" => "15:00:00"
]
```

That's exactly what I told the code to do, but It's not what I expected, It should only behave like this when I edit the customer session.

I have no idea how to solve this dumb logic, I tried poping and shifting the array, but it didn't worked properly. I'm just lost and stuck in this problem for weeks... Would be glad if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Forgot to mention that both the weekly days or the stored days might have different sizes, like I might have 3 days stored weekly in the database but I'm sending only one (deleted 2 of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you just want to do:

```
foreach($periodWeek as $periodDay) {
    $foundMatch = false;
    foreach($weekDays as $weekDay) {
        if ($weekDay['weekDay'] == $periodDay['weekDay'] &&
            $weekDay['startTime'] == $periodDay['startTime'] &&
            $weekDay['endTime'] == $periodDay['endTime'])
        {
            $foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$foundMatch) {
        $sessions[] = $weekDay;
    }
}
```

Also, instead of

```
if ($weekDay['weekDay'] == $periodDay['weekDay'] &&
        $weekDay['startTime'] == $periodDay['startTime'] &&
        $weekDay['endTime'] == $periodDay['endTime'])
```

you can just do:

```
if ($weekDay == $periodDay)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php:

> $a == $b  Equality    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.

Or, the shortest version I can think of:

```
foreach($periodWeek as $periodDay) {
    foreach($weekDays as $weekDay) {
        if ($weekDay == $periodDay) continue 2;
    }
    $sessions[] = $weekDay;
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked when I edited one session... I get a duplicated array, and if I edit both, I get 2 duplicated arrays. :(

Comment: Seems to work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ee16cb97fc72fdd601ddde849063adb06772d72

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it's working here now, Thanks Dave, you rock. :)